# Show that $f(x)g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} d_n(x-a)^{n}$ where $d_n= \sum_{k=0}^{n} b_kc_{n-k}$ knowing $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let's say we have two series $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n(x-a)^{n}$ and $g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n(x-a)^{n}$. We now that the radius of convergence of these series is accordingly $R_1$ and $R_2$.

Show that if the previous statements are true then exists such series that $f(x)g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} d_n(x-a)^{n}$ where $d_n= \sum_{k=0}^{n} b_kc_{n-k}$. Show also that the radius of convergence of this series is $R \geq \min\{R_1,R_2\}$.

Any help would be appreciated because the first time ever I do not have any ideas to even move a bit further with this problem.

Comment: That is the [Cauchy product of two power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Cauchy_product_of_two_power_series)

Comment: Okay, but how it explains the radius part or how should one show it?

Comment: If $|x-a| < \min(R_1, R_2)$ then both series are absolutely convergent, and therefore their Cauchy product.